How to create exception filter that catch exceptions from non-http processes like schedulers or consumers?
at Nest we have Exception Filter, and can catch errors from http exception filter. and other things like websockets or rpc, but I want to catch scheduler errors, or consumer errors, so I want to build an exception filter for them to catch errors.
How can you do it with Nest way?
